# Sequent calculus for propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, sequent-calculus

I think the [propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) must have a translation into the language of [Gentzen's sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus). I suppose, to obtain Gentzen's version of this we should just remove from LK the rules with the quantifiers, but, perhaps, we should also remove something more, maybe the cut rule... Can anybody clarify this to me and give a reference?

Comment: I mean, remove quantors and everything connected to them (in the language and everywhere).

Comment: @amWhy I don't know what will be the analogs of theories in this situation. There will be no quantifiers, but perhaps the construction will not be absolutely senseless... That is my question.

Comment: I asked because I am sure that this is well-known and elementary.

Comment: We are not a "do all the work necessary to test my conjecture for me" site.   We will confirm, validate a particular (of reasonable length) proof, or point out flaws...etc.

Comment: OK, I can remove the second question.

Comment: To get a Gentzen system for propositional logic just remove the 4 rules for the introduction of the quantifiers. You don't  need anything else. Cut is eliminable either way, so it doesn't matter. A standard reference is Troelstra's book Basic Proof Theory, I would say.

Comment: I edited my previous comment but in case you didn't see it, I think a standard reference is Troelstra's book Basic Proof Theory.

Comment: Thanks,@Sergei.  The question is now far more tractable. Cheers!

Comment: @Apostolos yes, I noticed this later, thank you!

Comment: Right now I cannot find an explicit mention in the book. If you do not believe this, it is very easy to verify that the rules are sound. Completeness follows by proving a complete set of Hilbert axioms of your choice and showing closure under modus ponens.

Comment: Yes, I don't see either...

Comment: You can see Gentzen's original papers, but also some well-know textbooks: G.Takeuti, [Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=Idl6K-W69NYC&pg=PA9) and Sara Negri &Jan von Plato, [Structural Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZvACGkn9138C&pg=PA25).

Comment: @Apostolos the impression is that we can remove much more than just the rules with quantifiers and the cut rule...

Comment: Which do you think should be removed?

Comment: Maybe I was not right when saying "much more", but it seems to me, this one (from Takeuti's book) is extra: 
$$
\frac{D,D,\Gamma\vdash\Delta}{D,\Gamma\vdash\Delta},\qquad
\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,D,D}{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,D}
$$

Comment: One of the powers of Gentzen's approach is that it's modular. Adding and removing logical connectives typically requires no adjustment to other logical connectives or meta-logical proofs (except to extend them to the new connective). This doesn't apply to the structural rules as changing those can have dramatic effects on the language as a whole. For the purposes of logic, quantifiers have no special effect. For type theory though, they impact the exchange rule which then does have broader implications.

Comment: @Apostolos , excuse me I see that I need this rule in the deduction of the "THEN-2" formula here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus